# [ipc bridge]MATLAB could not recognize function 'geometry_msgs_Twist'

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install the ipc-bridge on Ubuntu 12.04 following the instruction in

alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge#Using

For the step 7 I could not compile the last four msgs successfully and I changed the last line in "ipc_bridge_ros.mk" to

```
$(CXX) -I./include $(ROS_CXXFLAGS) $(IPC_BRIDGE_CXXFLAGS) -lstdc++ $(IPC_LFLAGS) -lipc $(ROS_LFLAGS) $(ROS_LIBS) $^ -o bin/$@ -lroscpp -lrosconsole -lroscpp_serialization -lipc
```

Every thing sets after this modification.

However, when I tried the demo provide in the instruction, my MATLAB give me the error message says that

```
Undefined function 'geometry_msgs_Twist' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

I also modified the ".bashrc" file to export the MEX to my MATLAB path and still does not working.

Anyone have a idea what's going wrong and how should I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66246/%5Bipc-bridge%5Dmatlab-could-not-recognize-function-%27geometry_msgs_twist%27/) by [xytmark](https://answers.ros.org/users/5279/xytmark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on 2016-01-20**:
Did you solve this problem? I met a same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use the ipc_bridge functions, you must first add the path of the specific binary to Matlab:
addpath('Address to the /bin directory of specific message which includes all the mex-compiled binary files')

---

Originally posted by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) with karma: 108 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0